# extern auto variable has no initializer

Tags: c++, time, clock

I need to use a global timestamp (std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()) in my c++ program. I declared it in the header file Header.h:

```
#include<chrono>
using namespace std;
extern auto start;
```

I want to initialize a value in main, so in main.cpp, I did:

```
#include"Header.h"
#include<chrono>
using namespace std;
auto start;
int main(){
   start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}
```

However, when compiling it, I got:

```
error: declaration of ‘auto start’ has no initializer
```

Can anybody tell me what I did wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can global auto variables be declared in h files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57805451/can-global-auto-variables-be-declared-in-h-files)

Comment: the newer Q&A has better answers (and clearer question IMO).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How is `auto` supposed to deduce the type of `start`?
You need to declare the type

```
extern std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start;
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm getting another error saying: "invalid use of template-name ‘std::chrono::time_point’ without an argument list", but I've checked the c++11 manual which says that  std::chrono::time_point is the return of high_resolution_clock. So what does this error mean?